# Estimating mle of parameter of exponential distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

I have a machine component whose life time is distributed as exponential with parameter $\lambda$

I switch on $n$ such components at time 0, then observe their performances during time $t$ and $t+z$ and see which one are still running during that time. I note binary variable for each such components with a random variable $X_i$ that takes 1 if fails and otherwise 0.

Based on this information, is it possible to obtain `mle` of $\lambda$?

Comment: Is this some homework exercise? In that case could you explain better (more precisely) where you get stuck and what your learning tasks are.

Comment: No. I am self-studying `mle` and put a real example that I wonder if `mle` can be applied. I can estimate `mle` for general case where I would have direct sample observations, however for this problem am not sure how to obtain `likelihood function` in terms of $\lambda$

Comment: "and see which one are still running during that time" does this mean that you effectively observe which ones are running untill time $t+z$? If a component stops running before time $t$, does this get noticed?

Comment: I was asking about the self-study aspect because the question has several tricky aspects (and could also be an interview question). As you see in the answer by zhanxiong one of the tricks is to realize that the observations are basically binomial distributed. Another aspect is interpretation of the question. Why do you only have those variables $X_i$, what happens to the information obtained from the action *"see which one are still running during that time"*, does this mean that you also have information about which one stopped before time $t$? And what about failure times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer: The final answer is pending on OP's further clarification.**

This is an example of type I censoring in survival analysis: instead of observing the exact life duration, a binary status is observed for a pre-specified time period. In your question, you also noticed that the observation $X_i$ takes values $0$ and $1$ -- this is a good start, the next step is simply to ascertain the distribution of $X_i$, which is governed by the underlying exponential distribution.

If $t > 0$, the likelihood function depends on further clarification on the problem.  Below is a solution assuming that no components failed before time $t$, which yields the likelihood for component $i$ as:
\begin{align}
P(X_i = 1) = P(t < T_i < t + z | T_i > t) = 1 - e^{-\lambda z},
\end{align}
where $T_i \sim \exp(\lambda)$ is the actual life duration (unobserved) of the $i$-th component. The likelihood function based on the sample $\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}$ is thus
\begin{align}
L(\lambda) = \prod_{i = 1}^n \left(1 - e^{-\lambda z}\right)^{X_i}\left(e^{-\lambda z}\right)^{1 - X_i}. \tag{1}
\end{align}

If denote $1 - e^{-\lambda z}$ by $p$, it is easy to verify that $(1)$ coincides with the likelihood function of a single observation $Y \sim B(n, p)$. Therefore, the MLE of $\lambda$ can be obtained by equating $1 - e^{-\lambda z}$ to $\sum X_i/n$ (of course, you may also maximize $(1)$ with respect to $\lambda$ to find $\hat{\lambda}$ directly), i.e.,
\begin{align}
1 - e^{-\hat{\lambda}z} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i, 
\end{align}
which yields
\begin{align}
\hat{\lambda} = - \frac{1}{z}\log\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. You mentioned that this is `type I censoring`. Could you please also refer some type of censoring with some practical examples, if possible please

Comment: The basic analysis is right, that you can convert it to a Bernoulli type distribution. But the probability should be different $$P(X_i = 1) = P(t<T_i < t+ z)$$ With the Bernoulli distribution we can estimate $p$ and equate that to $\lambda$, but there might be multiple $\lambda$ that correspond to this (or more problematic, there is no $\lambda$ that corresponds with it, and you have to figure the solution differently, by finding the $\lambda$ that maximises $p$).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Good catch, will update.  On the other hand, I don't understand why not setting $t = 0$ by all means...

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus In fact, if $t > 0$, I think the correct likelihood for $i$ should be $P(t < T_i < t + z | T_i > t)$ -- otherwise the subject wouldn't enter the experiment.  Then, by the memoryless property of exponential distribution, the likelihood doesn't change.  Though I am not 100% sure if I should use $P(t < T_i < t + z)$ or $P(t < T_i < t + z | T_i > t)$.

Comment: I am actually not sure about my comment. I do not know the meaning of *"see which one are still running during that time"*, and what information this is. But if we only observe information of failures between $t$ and $t+z$, then you will get something like solving $e^{-t\hat\lambda} - e^{-(t+z)\hat\lambda} = \hat{p}$ which may (and probably will) have two solutions for $\hat\theta$.

Comment: @BrianSmith Any good survival analysis textbook talks about this topic.  For example, Section 1.1 of *The Statistical Analysis of Failure Time Data* by Kalbfleisch and Prentice.  By the way, can you clarify why the machine was switched on at time $0$ but the observing with was set to be $[t, t + z]$ $(t > 0)$? What if some components failed before $t$? Can you count those failed before $t$?

Comment: @Zhanxiong `why the machine was switched on at time 0 but the observing with was set to be [,+] (>0)?` - this is how experiment is designed. Yes I think if some components fail before the experimenter enters at time `t`, then those components will be counted as already failed

Comment: @BrianSmith If so, your experiment is no different from counting failures in the period $[0, t + z]$, because failures in $[0, t]$ will also be counted -- that's why I thought the design is quite weird.

Comment: BTW, do you think this is a good design? Will it make any difference if the experimenter somehow could exclude the components which are already failed before time `t` than otherwise?

Comment: I don't think it is a good design, basically it is counterintuitive and not economical.  The normal experiment will start counting from time $0$ as soon as machines are turned on (which is both more economical and easier to analyze), there is no need to wait for a period lasting $t$.

Comment: Thanks. I was asking from inference pov. If experimenter would have noted already failed components and exclude them from analysis then will this information can lead to better (powerful?) inference about $\lambda$?

Comment: No, it won't lead to "better inference" either -- the reason is simple, the more data you collected, the better inference you can do. To summarize, unless you are trying to make a very contrived puzzle (even so, you need to clarify all the details in your question), it is pointless to design your experiment this way in my opinion.